# Using different CSS files on iOS and Android when app is built with Phonegap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, ratchet-2

I'm building a Phonegap app using Ratchet, and I'm using Phonegap Build.

Ratchet offers specific CSS files for iOS and Android, and I'd like to use the appropriate styles on each platform. However, ideally I'd like to avoid the overhead of detecting the platform and loading the CSS based on that.

I'm not holding out much hope, but is there a way to change what CSS file is used on each platform **when the app is built**, rather than detecting it using JavaScript and loading a different CSS file? It's not worth ditching Phonegap Build for the regular version over this issue, nor is it worth switching to manually uploading the files separately, but it is an annoyance. I'm thinking along the lines of some kind of hook that lets you overwrite different files based on the platform, or a way to override the file for a given platform.

I fully expect the answer to be "No", but I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Stumbled across a possible way to do what I want today. Phonegap Build recently added support for pulling from branches other than the master branch, so what I could do is maintain an iOS and Android branch, with the only difference being the CSS loaded and the config file (so as to limit each branch to the required platform), and develop in the master branch but continually merge the changes into the iOS and Android branches. Then I could trigger the build from the different branches separately to create the iOS and Android versions

Answer (score 0):

You can add your device specific CSS files in the css folder under the www directory.
Include those relevant css files in the index.html file markup

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Android/android.css" type="text/css">
```

[image]

Comment: That's for regular Phonegap, not the Phonegap Build service.

Comment: What is the issue here? You need to upload the files (containing the HTML, CSS and JS) to the Phone gap build service and the build will automatically create the binaries for you right?. So just include the CSS for Android and ask it to build ONLY for android. Then make changes to the index.html include specific iPhone files and then build exclusively for iPHone. I know you will not get the binaries in a SINGLE pass. You have to do it each time for a DEVICE specific build. Am I thinking right? Or totally on a different track? Do you want the binaries 2 b build in SINGLE pass for all DEVICEs?

Comment: Well, that would work, but at present I use a Git repository as the source for the build and it isn't worth switching to uploading the assets manually.

Comment: If you don't want the manual switching of index/css, what is wrong with having the app detect OS and loading the appropriate css via js?

Comment: It's more that it's cumbersome than anything else. I'm currently loading the CSS via JavaScript and it works, but it's not the most elegant of solutions. My ideal solution would be either a way to override the file content for a specific platform only, or a way to run something like sed to to a search and replace for one platform only. Like I said, I don't think it's going to happen, but it would be handy.